# Использована неинициализированная переменная char. C++

Tags: c++, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (char ch = cin.get() && ch != '=')
    {
       //что нибудь...
    }
}
```

При вводе любого символа - исключение об неинициализированности переменной `ch`. Почему здесь ловится исключение? `ch` вполне вроде инициализируется.

Comment: нужно ставить скобки вокруг char ch = cin.get() и учитывать, что cin.get() символ перевода строки тоже читает, поэтому далеко не всегда это правильно. Я вам писал  ответ, не имея возможности выделить время на раздумье, и там была не только эта ошибка, поэтому удалил. Будет днем время, если никто не ответит правильно, я восстановлю в исправленном виде

Comment: @ARHovsepyan понял, но все равно ваш ответ показался мне хорошим и хотелось разобраться, почему он не рабочий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не заморачивался и использовал цикл `for`, в котором все совершенно очевидно и давно решено :)

```
for(char ch = cin.get(); ch != '='; ch = cin.get())
```

Впрочем, лучше так:

```
for(char ch; cin.get(ch) && ch != '=';)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот это:

```
while (char ch = cin.get() && ch != '=')
```

делает не то, что вы думаете. Это то же самое, что и:

```
while (char ch = (cin.get() && ch != '='))
```

Правильнее написать так:

```
while (char ch = cin.get(); ch && ch != '=')
```

Но я так понимаю, что в левой части `&&` вы пытались проверить, что символ считался успешно, а не сравнить его с нулем. (`.get()` при ошибке возвращает не ноль.)

Тогда лучше написать так:

```
while (char ch = cin.get(); cin && ch != '=')
```

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.while

Answer (score -2):

Подозреваю `char ch = cin.get()` инициализируется только для первого условия. Грубо говоря, переменная, объявленная в условии будет доступна только для этого условия, но не более.